# Using Base64 in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, http, base64

I am converting my image to byte array then to base64 string it coverts and decodes perfectly but when i saves that string to mysql database using php and retrieves it from database it do not decodes that and says bad base64

Here is my code.

php

```
$sql = "insert into users(username, password, email,mob,imagetext)
                            values ('".$username."', '".$password."', '".$email."', '".$mob."', '".$imageText."') ";
```

android

encode

```
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
 Bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
 byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
 String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Decode

```
 byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(value, Base64.DEFAULT);                     
 b = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
```

Comment: I think it wraps the string before saving inside mysql.

Comment: You are not providing the php decode function...

Comment: I inserting as a text using PHP the encode and decode is handled by android code. Is that correct way? I am new in coding !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing the Base64 encoding options from Base64.DEFAULT.
You should use Base64.URL_SAFE which will use characters that wont need to be url encoded when sent to your php script.
Also consider using Base64.NO_WRAP which will prevent MIME new lines from being added to your base 64 output.

Answer (score 1):

Based on above answer,
Encode :

```
 String imageEncoded = Base64.encodeToString(b,Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE);
```

Decode :

```
 byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(value, Base64.NO_WRAP | Base64.URL_SAFE);
```